# Command-line control login remotely from another computer

Tags: command-line, remote-access, remote-login

I need a way to get command-line control of a computer remotely, from another computer. That is, I need a secure way to log in from another machine on the network using a terminal.

Answer (score 13):

You can use ssh. You'll need to install an ssh server on the remote machine:

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

You can then connect to the computer with:

```
ssh username@remote-pcs-ip
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to take a look for SSH. SSH stands for Secure SHell. In very non-technical terms, SSH allows you to access a system running a SSH server over a network. This other system can be another computer in your home or a remote system on the other side of the planet. SSH will allow you to connect to that other system and communicate with it securely. All the data passed back and forth is encrypted, so you don’t have to worry about people sniffing your passwords or valuable data.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys

For more information and easy to use tutorial read [this](https://chrisjean.com/2009/02/19/ssh-tutorial-for-ubuntu-linux/) and [this](http://teamprincipia.wordpress.com/2008/05/29/beginning-ssh-on-ubuntu/).